# How while from Json array

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to build an app that will display latitude and longitude in a TextView, separated by "|", from a JSON file. But it's only showing me the last record, and not the others.

As an example, I need the TextView to show this:

```
6.3415247,-75.5656870|6.3395370,-75.5656870|6.3456380,-75.5491314
```

From this JSON, generated by PHP:

```
[
  {
    "id": "12",
    "sede": "Bucaros",
    "r_lat": "6.3415247",
    "r_lng": "-75.5577208"
  },
  {
    "id": "13",
    "sede": "Bucaros",
    "r_lat": "6.3395370",
    "r_lng": "-75.5656870"
  },
  {
    "id": "15",
    "sede": "Perez",
    "r_lat": "6.3456380",
    "r_lng": "-75.5491314"
  }
]
```

The code I have so far is:

```
Public void getMarkers() {
        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.e("Response: ", response);

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    String getObject = jObj.getString("saagMRK");
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(getObject);

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        title = jsonObject.getString(TITLE);
                        latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString(LAT)), Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString(LNG)));
                        coor =  jsonObject.getString(LAT) + "," + jsonObject.getString(LNG) +  "|";

                        // Menambah data marker untuk di tampilkan ke google map
                        addMarker(latLng, title);

                        tv2.setText(coor);

                    }



                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // JSON error
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(PathGoogleMapActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_json_obj);

    }


}
```

Comment: response no problem, the problem is that only show me the last JSON Item this: 6.3456380,-75.5491314|  ---- I need print alls Item this: 6.3415247,-75.5656870|6.3395370,-75.5656870|6.3456380,-75.5491314, i don't know how i do

Comment: tv2.setText(coor); should be out the for loop...@Matheo Espitia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In for loop assign lat and long like below:

```
coor = coor + jsonObject.getString(LAT) + "," + jsonObject.getString(LNG) +  "|";
```

And set text to textview after for loop block:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    title = jsonObject.getString(TITLE);
                    latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString(LAT)), Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString(LNG)));
                    coor = coor + jsonObject.getString(LAT) + "," + jsonObject.getString(LNG) +  "|";

                    // Menambah data marker untuk di tampilkan ke google map
                    addMarker(latLng, title);



}
tv2.setText(coor);
```

Comment: Hi, work but show null in the first item this: null6.3490548,-75.5580200|6.3453442,-75.5516705|6.3376373...

Comment: @MatheoEspitia Don't just declare coor in starting. Initialize coor to empty string like:  String coor = " "

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
  String coor = "";  
  for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        title = jsonObject.getString(TITLE);
        latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString(LAT)), Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString(LNG)));
        coor = coor +  jsonObject.getString(LAT) + "," + jsonObject.getString(LNG) +  "|";

        // Menambah data marker untuk di tampilkan ke google map
         addMarker(latLng, title);

  }
  if(coor.length() > 0){
    coor.substring(0,coor.length()-1)
  }
  tv2.setText(coor);
```